# Importing a formula from a text file

Tags: csv, formula

I'm making a simple program that'll test children's problem solving skills, essentially a quiz where the program pulls a question from a text file, then prints that questions, and checks if the user inputs the right answer.

So far, I've had this as my text file:

```
David collects 2 comics each month for 3 months. For the next 2 months, he only collects one each month. How many comics does David collect altogether?,8
Sally gives out 4 party bags at the end of her party. Inside each party bag are 5 balloons. How many balloons does Sally give out?,20
```

Then I put that into a 2D array where [0][0] is the first question and [0][1] is the first answer.
That works, but I'd like to use random numbers, meaning the program has to calculate the answer itself. That would mean my text file looks like this:

```
David collects X comics each month for Y months. For the next Z months, he only collects one each month. How many comics does David collect altogether?,((X*Y)+Z)
Sally gives out X party bags at the end of her party. Inside each party bag are Y balloons. How many balloons does Sally give out?,(X*Y)
```

Where X,Y and Z are random numbers and the part after the comma is the formula to calculate the answer. To print out the question, I can use `if (Question.contains("X")){Question = Question.replace("X", A);}` where A is a random int. But how can I make Java calculate the answer? If I have `int answer=((X*Y)+Z)` inside a string, how can I convert this string to code? I read that the Java Compiler API can change a string to usable code but how does this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    vars.put("X", 2);
    vars.put("Y", 1);
    vars.put("Z", 3);
    System.out.println("result = "+engine.eval("((X*Y)+Z)", new SimpleBindings(vars)));
 }
}
```

using javax.script you can parse and solve simple formula, and to generate random numbers

`(int) (Math.random()*20))`  should do it

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. To create random numbers, I usually use `int a=random.nextInt(10)`, is there any difference between this and the `(int) (Math.random()*20))` you mentioned?

Comment: It's basically the same, unless you are interested in thread safety, and unformity of the distribution any method that give you something random should do it ^^. The main difference is that math.random is thread safe, there is other differences in the usage of both but that's important only if you generate very large set of numbers and want uniformity on the distribution.